# Z80 computer design peer-review

Tags: computers, z80, code-review

this is a re-post as I was unable to get any help on other forums. I have designed and built a simple Z80 computer system with 32K RAM, Z80B at 4mhz, 32K ROM, and a UART. The only problem with it is that the system doesn't seem to work. So, I am asking to have somebody peer-review my code and schematics.

```
    org 0x0000
uart_init:
    ld a, 0x80
    out (0x03), a
    ld a, 12
    out(0x00), a
    ld a, 00
    out(0x01), a
    ld a, 0x03
    out(0x03),a
uart_out:
    in a, (0x05)
    bit 5, a
    jp z, uart_out
    ld a, 0x41
    out (0x00), a
    jp uart_out
```

[image: Z80 System Processor]
[image: Z80 System IO]
[image: Z80 System Memory]

Comment: Is this the only problem? Did you turn the power on? Does it fetch anything from memory upon release of reset? How do you plan to put your code into Z80? What is in the EPROM?

Comment: Your UART's CS0 and CS1 pins should be tied high, not low.

Comment: @brhans. I see the same problem. OP has disabled his UART with simple mistakes.

Comment: We discourage broad, open-ended design review questions here on EE.SE: The answer(s) tend to become long strings of unrelated edits and/or comments. While this might help you with your immediate problems, it is of no value to the site overall. We DO allow design review questions in which you explain your choices and then focus on a few points about which you still have doubts. To get a better feel of what is or is not acceptable, search for "design review" on the meta site.

Comment: there is no solution to `system doesn't seem to work`... `I was unable to get any help on other forums` ... no wonder, you provide no information as to what the circuit is supposed to do, and no information about what it actually does

Answer (score 2):

Are you absolutely sure that this is the correct way to connect a bus:

[image]

**Every schematic package** that I have ever worked with had special provisions for depicting BUS connections that were different from how single wire nets are connected. As shown in your schematic it would appear that you have shorted all the data bus pins together and all the address bus pins together. If this is the case it is no wonder that it does not work.

Comment: I'm guessing the OP didn't actually make a PCB from this schematic. It's probably just a mess of wires stuck in a breadboard. Who knows what errors there might be in that?

Answer (score 2):

I found a few errors in your circuit:-

1. TL16C550 CS0 and CS1 should be pulled high, not low.
   The way you have them wired the chip can never be selected.
2. RI, DCD and CTS should also be pulled high. The states of these
   inputs shouldn't affect transmission and reception, but floating pins 
   can increase current draw and confuse software.
3. 27C256 Vpp (pin 1) should be tied to Vcc, not ground.
   The chip *may* still work with Vpp tied to ground (a Microchip
   27C256 that I tested did) but all the datasheets I examined said
   it should be connected to Vcc.

The software works (I tried it on my Z80 board which is almost identical to yours) but you should add a delay at startup to ensure that all peripherals are stable before the CPU accesses them.

When using a simple RC timed reset generator the CPU may come out of reset before the 16C550, then the CPU will try to initialize the UART before it is ready. My board had a large capacitor on the CPU reset line so I needed a startup delay of at least 20ms (I have since added a Schmitt trigger buffer between the reset switch and CPU reset, and it now works without any delay).

Some other things (not made clear on the schematics) which may need attention:-

- You should have a 100nF ceramic capacitor between Vcc and ground of all ICs. Without these bypass capacitors the circuit could suffer from random glitches, due to current spikes caused by the chips as they switch between logic states.
- Check that the TL16C550 pin numbers are correct for the chip package you
  are using!
- For reliable operation the Z80 requires a clock that swings from <=0.8V to >=Vcc - 0.6V (higher than the normal TTL minimum high level of 2.4V). Make sure your clock generator is supplying a strong enough signal.
- the pinouts on your 9 pin serial plug are for [Data Terminal equipment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_terminal_equipment). to connect your Z80 board to a PC you will need a 'null-modem' cable which swaps TX/RX and DSR/DTR.